# What does a bone icon on an item mean?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

What does it mean when an item in my inventory is labeled with a bone icon?

[image: Long Hatchet EX with a bone icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bone icon indicates a material that can be used in crafting. It can be especially useful for identifying weapons or relics you may want to save for crafting recipes you haven't unlocked yet. You can see the icons for all item types in the Refined Search menu.

Note that while seemingly any item labeled as a material is used in a crafting recipe, not all crafting ingredients are labeled as materials. (ie: Salt, Beast Meat, Sainona Greens)

[image: Bone icon in refined search menu]